# Qt Stylesheet: Setting the icon mode for a QTabBar

Tags: css, qt, qt4

I have a QTabBar with a stylesheet applied to it. I create icons for the tabs through QIcon, so the normal/disabled/selected modes are set through that. I have been trying to find a way to set the QTabBar's unselected tabs to the disabled mode through the global stylesheet without knowing what the tab's icon is.

So, in other words, I have a tool that has multiple tabs. The tabs set the icons through QIcon when I build the tabs. I want to have a global stylesheet that is applied on the whole tool, and sets the unselected tabs' icons to disabled.

Comment: No such thing. Set icons through the stylesheet to achieve your aim.

Answer (score 1):

Try `QTabBar::tab:!selected`.

You have the options of:

- `QTabBar::tab` (default tab properties)
- `QTabBar::tab:selected:top` (if on top)
- `QTabBar::tab:selected:bottom` (if on bottom)
- `QTabBar::tab:selected` (currently in focus)
- `QTabBar::tab:!selected` (not selected tab, can be skinned with inactive grey's)
- `QTabBar::tab:first:selected` (first selected tab)
- `QTabBar::tab:last:selected` (string through all other selected tabs to last selected tab)
- `QTabBar::tab:hover` (change appearance on not-selected (!) if hovered over)
- `QTabBar::tab:selected:hover` (change appearance of active tab)